# Checking divisibility of a range of numbers with no repetition of digits

Tags: java

I wrote the following program to count the numbers that are divisible by 12 but contain no repetition of digits. eg. the number 144 is not to be considered even though it is divisible by 12 as a repetition of digit 4 is present. The problem is that I get no output. I tried changing the range of for loop from 12...54321 to 12...1000 and even 12...24. I still get no output. I can't seem to find what the problem is. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code. Or just suggest me a better code/solution to the problem. Thanks...

```
class mod12
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(int num=12;num<=54321;num+=12)
        {
            boolean repetition=false;
            int digits[]=new int[10];
            int length=0;
            while (num!=0)
            {
                digits[length++]=num%10;
                num=num/10;
            }
            for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<length; j++)
                {
                    if(i!=j)
                    {
                        if(digits[i]==digits[j])
                        {
                            repetition=true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(repetition==false)
            {count++;}
        }
        System.out.println("There are "+count+" numbers satisfying the condition");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the while loop you decrease `num`, effectively moving the `for` loop backwards, so it never completes. Using a temporary variable instead would solve the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int count=0;
    for(int num=12;num<=54321;num+=12)
    {
        boolean repetition=false;
        int digits[]=new int[10];
        int length=0;
        int tempNum = num; // Here
        while (tempNum !=0)
        {
            digits[length++]=tempNum %10;
            tempNum =tempNum /10;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<length; j++)
            {
                if(i!=j)
                {
                    if(digits[i]==digits[j])
                    {
                        repetition=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(repetition==false)
        {count++;}
    }
    System.out.println("There are "+count+" numbers satisfying the condition");
}
```

**EDIT:**

Regardless of the original question, note you can shorten your code considerably by using a `Set` to track the digits:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 0;
    NUMBERS:
    for (int num = 12; num <= 54321; num += 12) {
        Set<Integer> digits = new HashSet<>();
        int tempNum = num;
        while (tempNum != 0) {
            int digit = tempNum % 10;
            if (!digits.add(digit)) {
                continue NUMBERS;
            }
            tempNum = tempNum / 10;
        }
        ++count;
    }
    System.out.println("There are "+count+" numbers satisfying the condition");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was a silly mistake but was making me go mad. Thanks for a quick response...